# Ajax requests and debug text?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have AJAX requests from which I get a JSON-format response, which is being attended to and everything works well.

The problem is when the application-level debug is on, some more info like SQL statements are outputted along with JSON and the things don't work.

**Question**: Is there a ways to selectively pick contents from the AJAX response, so that the response works regardless of whatever comes along with it.

I use jQuery.

Comment: can you post the json response which you get with app debug on

Comment: it could be anything, I am talking generic

Comment: Even if there *is* a way to do what you're specifically asking, it's not the **right** way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Make it so that your server-side application *doesn't produce this malformed output*.

This is why outputting debug to the main output is bad. You should be outputting to some internal logfile on the server that doesn't affect the business output.

If desperate, you could have the debug messages injected into the JSON.

Comment: Additionally, whatever debugger is being used *should* be able (if necessary) to just add those messages to the json output automatically on the condition that it is an ajax request, rather than print them directly. So - yeah, like you said in the last part :)

Comment: @Wesley: Indeed. The last server-side app I wrote would catch exceptions at the top level, and output _only_ `{'_app_error':'Exception text here'}`. Then an extension to `$.ajax` in jQuery for JSON-format requests would detect this, intercept the request, turn it into a failing request and call the user-defined `app_error` handler (if available). Of course, error message are not the same as debug output.

Answer (score 0):

no. you can't just parse json code with another mess/garbage. If you have FIXED value of that json, you can make substring from it.